# NodeJS / psql: Getting error "connection terminated unexpectedly"

Tags: node.js, postgresql, psql

I am trying to set up a node js application with a psql database. When I run `node App.js` I get the error "Error: Connection terminated unexpectedly
at Connection.con.once (/home/bismarck/Documents/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:132:73)"

I have confirmed that the credentials I am using in my application are correct and that I can query the mydb database using those creentials. I also confirm that the sql service is running using `systemctl service start`. Here is the relevant Code.

```js
const config = {
 21         host: 'localhost',
 22         user: username,
 23         password: password,
 24         database: 'mydb',
 25         port: port,
 26 }
 27 
 28 const client = new Client(config);
 29 client.connect(err => {
 30         if (err) throw err;
 31         else {
 32                 getData();
 33         }
 34 });
```

Comment: It's too late to comment. But, I am wondering if you were able to find out the cause of the issue and solve it?

Comment: Have you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too,
in my case it was cause i tried to connect db in **production**.

so, I added `ssl` to Pool,
like this:

```
const pool = new Pool({
    connectionString: connectionString,
    ssl: {rejectUnauthorized: false},
});
```

Hope it helps you too...